# Getting back same number of rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code below that allows me to move the value from `Green Fruits Table` to `Random Fruits Table` and vice versa but the problem is that after I move all the value from `Green Fruits Table` back to `Random Fruit Table` all the value comes back as a single row but I want it to return the value like how it was originally. Is there any simple way to fix this Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated?

```js
var obj = {};
var obj2 = {};

var key = "Red Fruits";
obj[key] = ['Apple', 'Cherry', 'Strawberry'];
var myArray = [];
myArray.push(obj);

var key2 = "Green Fruits";
obj[key2] = ['Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado'];
var myArray2 = [];
myArray2.push(obj);

var key3 = "Random Fruits";
obj2[key3] = ['Kiwi', 'Pomegranate', 'Honeydew', 'Plum', 'Mango', 'Lime', 'Pineapple', 'Starfruit', 'Cantaloupe', 'Blueberry'];
var myArray3 = [];
myArray3.push(obj2);

function redraw(obj) {

  var $header = $("<tr>"),
    cols = 0,
    bodyString = "";

  $.each(obj, function(key, values) {
    cols = Math.max(cols, values.length);
    $header.append($('<th/>').text(key));
  });
  for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
    bodyString += '<tr>';
    $.each(obj, function(key, values) {
      bodyString += '<td>' +
        (values[i] ? values[i] : "") +
        '</td>';
    });
    bodyString += '</tr>';
  }
  $('.fruitsclass thead').html($header);
  $('.fruitsclass tbody').html(bodyString);

  var bodyString = '<tr>';
  var headString = '';
  $.each(obj2[key3], function(index) {
    if (index % 5 == 0 && index > 0) {
      bodyString += ('</tr><tr>');
    }
    bodyString += ('<td>' + obj2[key3][index] + '</td>');
  });
  bodyString += '</tr>';
  headString += ('<tr><th colspan="' + obj2[key3].length + '">' + 'Suggested Fruits' + '</th></tr>');
  $('.carsclass tbody').html(bodyString);
  $('.carsclass thead').html(headString);
}


function listener(obj) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", "#carsid td", function() {
      data = this.innerHTML;
      k1 = Object.keys(obj2).find(k => obj2[k].indexOf(data) >= 0)
      index = obj2[k1].indexOf(data);
      obj2[k1].splice(index, 1);
      obj[key2].push(data);
      var element = $(this).detach();
      $('#fruitsid > tbody').append('<tr><td></td><td class="new-green-fruit">' + element.html() + '</td></tr>');
    });
  });

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('click', 'td.new-green-fruit', function() {
      data2 = this.innerHTML;
      k2 = Object.keys(obj).find(k => obj[k].indexOf(data2) >= 0)
      index2 = obj[k2].indexOf(data2);
      obj[k2].splice(index2, 1);
      obj2[key3].push(data2);
      $(this).parent().detach();
      var element2 = $(this).detach();
      $('#carsid > tbody').append('<td>' + element2.html() + '</td>');
    });
  });
}
redraw(obj);
listener(obj);
```

```css
.class {
  font-family: Open Sans;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center
}

table.skillsTable th {
  border-left: 1px solid #AAA5A4;
  border-right: 1px solid #AAA5A4;
  color: #0080ff;
  font-weight: normal;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #AAA5A4;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

table.skillsTable {
  float: left;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 70%
}

table.pillstable {
  float: left;
  width: 70% table-row:fixed;
}

table.skillsTable td {
  border-left: 1px solid #AAA5A4;
  border-right: 1px solid #AAA5A4;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-left: 11px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

div {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.new-green-fruit {
  color: lime;
}

table.pilltable td {
  padding: 8px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: #2196f3;
  color: white;
}

table.pilltable th {
  font-weight: normal;
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="//#" />

</head>

<body>
  <div id="result"> </div>
  <div class="center">
    <table id="fruitsid" class="fruitsclass skillsTable class">
      <thead></thead>
      <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div class="center">
    <table cellspacing="5" id="carsid" cellspacing="5" class="carsclass pilltable class">
      <thead></thead>
      <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, I am adding some `data` properties in your random fruits, which I'm later using to get the right `row` and `column` to insert at. Have added some comments in code below to navigate.

Probably not the best implementation, but something like this should help you. (See snippet).

```js
      
var obj = {}
var obj2 = {}

var key = 'Red Fruits'
obj[key] = ['Apple', 'Cherry', 'Strawberry']
var myArray = []
myArray.push(obj)

var key2 = 'Green Fruits'
obj[key2] = ['Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado']
var myArray2 = []
myArray2.push(obj)

var key3 = 'Random Fruits'
obj2[key3] = ['Kiwi', 'Pomegranate', 'Honeydew', 'Plum', 'Mango', 'Lime', 'Pineapple', 'Starfruit', 'Cantaloupe', 'Blueberry']
var myArray3 = []
myArray3.push(obj2)

function redraw (obj) {

  var $header = $('<tr>'),
    cols = 0,
    bodyString = ''

  $.each(obj, function (key, values) {
    cols = Math.max(cols, values.length)
    $header.append($('<th/>').text(key))
  })
  for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
    bodyString += '<tr>'
    $.each(obj, function (key, values) {
      bodyString += '<td>' +
        (values[i] ? values[i] : '') +
        '</td>'
    })
    bodyString += '</tr>'
  }
  $('.fruitsclass thead').html($header)
  $('.fruitsclass tbody').html(bodyString)

  var bodyString = '<tr>'
  var headString = ''
  $.each(obj2[key3], function (index) {
    if (index % 5 == 0 && index > 0) {
      bodyString += ('</tr><tr>')
    }
    // adding data row and data column attributes
    bodyString += ('<td data-row="' + parseInt(index / 5) + '" data-column="' + index % 5 + '">' + obj2[key3][index] + '</td>')
  })
  bodyString += '</tr>'
  headString += ('<tr><th colspan="' + obj2[key3].length + '">' + 'Suggested Fruits' + '</th></tr>')
  $('.carsclass tbody').html(bodyString)
  $('.carsclass thead').html(headString)
}

function listener (obj) {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '#carsid td', function () {
      data = this.innerHTML
      k1 = Object.keys(obj2).find(k => obj2[k].indexOf(data) >= 0)
      index = obj2[k1].indexOf(data)
      obj2[k1].splice(index, 1)
      obj[key2].push(data)
      var element = $(this).clone() // cloning to keep the placeholder in random fruits
      $(this).replaceWith('<td></td>') // and removing it's content.
      element.addClass('new-green-fruit')
      // using outerHTML to get the whole attributes of the fruit including row and col
      $('#fruitsid > tbody').append('<tr><td></td>' + element[0].outerHTML + '</tr>')
    })
  })

  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').on('click', 'td.new-green-fruit', function () {
      data2 = this.innerHTML
      k2 = Object.keys(obj).find(k => obj[k].indexOf(data2) >= 0)
      index2 = obj[k2].indexOf(data2)
      obj[k2].splice(index2, 1)
      obj2[key3].push(data2)
      $(this).parent().detach()
      var element2 = $(this).detach()
      var row = element2.data('row')
      var col = element2.data('column')
      // inserting in right row and column gathered from above.
      $($($('#carsid > tbody tr')[row]).find('td')[col]).replaceWith(element2)
      return false;
    })
  })
}

redraw(obj)
listener(obj)
```

```css
.class {
  font-family: Open Sans;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center
}

table.skillsTable th {
  border-left: 1px solid #AAA5A4;
  border-right: 1px solid #AAA5A4;
  color: #0080ff;
  font-weight: normal;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #AAA5A4;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

table.skillsTable {
  float: left;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 70%
}

table.pillstable {
  float: left;
  width: 70% table-row:fixed;
}

table.skillsTable td {
  border-left: 1px solid #AAA5A4;
  border-right: 1px solid #AAA5A4;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-left: 11px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

div {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.new-green-fruit {
  color: lime;
}

table.pilltable td {
  padding: 8px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: #2196f3;
  color: white;
}

table.pilltable th {
  font-weight: normal;
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="//#" />

  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="result"> </div>
    <div class="center">
      <table id="fruitsid" class="fruitsclass skillsTable class">
        <thead></thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div class="center">
      <table cellspacing="5" id="carsid" cellspacing="5" class="carsclass pilltable class">
        <thead></thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Bobby can you elaborate what error you see? Snippet is working perfectly well for me above.

Comment: the console log prints `{
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 162,
  "colno": 24
}`

Comment: @bobby http://jsfiddle.net/0odznmq3/ - here is the fiddle with same code. Does it give you the same error?

Comment: There's no error but the cell looks kinda weird but it's okay already because i changed most of my codes already. Btw may i ask if you can take a look at my current codes there's a weird bug i cant seem to fix whenever i try to move the values from `Green Fruits` back to `Suggested Fruits` all the value's from `Green Fruits` disappear and i have no idea why. Here my JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9frs47q1/1/

Comment: because you are doing `$(this).parent().detach();`  instead of `$(this).detach();`

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you push the elements outside the rows and you don't save their positions. Solution: save the position and insert inside `tr`

```js
function getPosition(data) {
  return {
    row: Number(data.split(' ')[0]),
    column: Number(data.split(' ')[1])
  };
}

Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('elem')).forEach(elem => {
  elem.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if(e.target.parentNode.classList.contains('tr')) {
      let position = getPosition(e.target.dataset.position);
      let row = document.querySelector('.tab').querySelectorAll('tr')[position.row];
      row.insertBefore(e.target, row.children[position.column]);
    } else {
      document.querySelector('.tr').appendChild(e.target);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.elems {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.elem {
  background: rgb(0, 120, 255);
  padding: 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table class='elems'>
  <tr class='tr'>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class='tab'>
  <tr><td class='elem' data-position='0 0'>ELem1</td>
    <td class='elem' data-position='0 1'>Long ELem2</td>
    <td class='elem' data-position='0 2'>Longer ELem3</td></tr>
  <tr><td class='elem' data-position='1 0'>Even Longer ELem4</td>
    <td class='elem' data-position='1 1'>Short ELem5</td>
    <td class='elem' data-position='1 2'>Just ELem6</td></tr>
</table>
```

You could also use flexbox

```js
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("elem")).forEach(elem => {
  elem.addEventListener('click', e => {
    document.querySelector('.flex-box').appendChild(e.target);
  });
});
```

```css
.flex-box {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.elem {
  background: rgb(0, 120, 255);
  padding: 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.flex-box .elem {
  flex: 1 0 content;
}
```

```html
<div class='elems'>
  <div class='elem'>ELem1</div>
  <div class='elem'>Long ELem2</div>
  <div class='elem'>Longer ELem3</div>
  <div class='elem'>Even Longer ELem4</div>
  <div class='elem'>Short ELem5</div>
  <div class='elem'>Just ELem6</div>
</div>
<div class='flex-box'></div>
```

This solution requires more code because you have to move elements from `table` to `div` (possible to avoid with some changes to the table). Other than that, the elements are not automatically stretched when using flexbox, so you don't have to play with the elements to prevent overstretching when one of them has long contents.
If you want to preserve the order, use the `order` property.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, I've created a new function `redraw_after(obj)` by slightly modifying your `redraw(obj)` function and placing both of the functions in the script. Now, just call the new `redraw_after(obj)` function after each of the listener functions to get the desired output.

What is happening here is that after each click, all the objects are redrawn to that 5 column in each row style. That's why it is working. Though, the new elements are added at the last of the queue each time, I guess the implementation is perfect, however.

```js
var obj = {};
var obj2 = {};

var key = "Red Fruits";
obj[key] = ['Apple', 'Cherry', 'Strawberry'];
var myArray = [];
myArray.push(obj);

var key2 = "Green Fruits";
obj[key2] = ['Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado'];
var myArray2 = [];
myArray2.push(obj);

var key3 = "Random Fruits";
obj2[key3] = ['Kiwi', 'Pomegranate', 'Honeydew', 'Plum', 'Mango', 'Lime', 'Pineapple', 'Starfruit', 'Cantaloupe', 'Blueberry'];
var myArray3 = [];
myArray3.push(obj2);

function redraw(obj) {

  var $header = $("<tr>"),
    cols = 0,
    bodyString = "";

  $.each(obj, function(key, values) {
    cols = Math.max(cols, values.length);
    $header.append($('<th/>').text(key));
  });
  for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
    bodyString += '<tr>';
    $.each(obj, function(key, values) {
      bodyString += '<td>' +
        (values[i] ? values[i] : "") +
        '</td>';
    });
    bodyString += '</tr>';
  }
  $('.fruitsclass thead').html($header);
  $('.fruitsclass tbody').html(bodyString);

  var bodyString = '<tr>';
  var headString = '';
  $.each(obj2[key3], function(index) {
    if (index % 5 == 0 && index > 0) {
      bodyString += ('</tr><tr>');
    }
    bodyString += ('<td>' + obj2[key3][index] + '</td>');
  });
  bodyString += '</tr>';
  headString += ('<tr><th colspan="' + obj2[key3].length + '">' + 'Suggested Fruits' + '</th></tr>');
  $('.carsclass tbody').html(bodyString);
  $('.carsclass thead').html(headString);
}

function redraw_after(obj) {

  var bodyString = "";


  var bodyString = '<tr>';
  var headString = '';
  $.each(obj2[key3], function(index) {
    if (index % 5 == 0 && index > 0) {
      bodyString += ('</tr><tr>');
    }
    bodyString += ('<td>' + obj2[key3][index] + '</td>');
  });
  bodyString += '</tr>';
  headString += ('<tr><th colspan="' + obj2[key3].length + '">' + 'Suggested Fruits' + '</th></tr>');
  $('.carsclass tbody').html(bodyString);
  $('.carsclass thead').html(headString);
}


function listener(obj) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", "#carsid td", function() {
      data = this.innerHTML;
      k1 = Object.keys(obj2).find(k => obj2[k].indexOf(data) >= 0)
      index = obj2[k1].indexOf(data);
      obj2[k1].splice(index, 1);
      obj[key2].push(data);
      var element = $(this).detach();
      $('#fruitsid > tbody').append('<tr><td></td><td class="new-green-fruit">' + element.html() + '</td></tr>');
      redraw_after(obj);
    });
  });

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('click', 'td.new-green-fruit', function() {
      data2 = this.innerHTML;
      k2 = Object.keys(obj).find(k => obj[k].indexOf(data2) >= 0)
      index2 = obj[k2].indexOf(data2);
      obj[k2].splice(index2, 1);
      obj2[key3].push(data2);
      $(this).parent().detach();
      var element2 = $(this).detach();
      $('#carsid > tbody').append('<td>' + element2.html() + '</td>');
      redraw_after(obj);
    });
  });

}
redraw(obj);
listener(obj);
```

```css
.class {
  font-family: Open Sans;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center
}

table.skillsTable th {
  border-left: 1px solid #AAA5A4;
  border-right: 1px solid #AAA5A4;
  color: #0080ff;
  font-weight: normal;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #AAA5A4;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

table.skillsTable {
  float: left;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 70%
}

table.pillstable {
  float: left;
  width: 70% table-row:fixed;
}

table.skillsTable td {
  border-left: 1px solid #AAA5A4;
  border-right: 1px solid #AAA5A4;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-left: 11px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

div {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.new-green-fruit {
  color: lime;
}

table.pilltable td {
  padding: 8px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: #2196f3;
  color: white;
}

table.pilltable th {
  font-weight: normal;
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="result"> </div>
<div class="center">
  <table id="fruitsid" class="fruitsclass skillsTable class">
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="center">
  <table cellspacing="5" id="carsid" class="carsclass pilltable class">
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```